# I need to generate new column based on two columns of dataframe, how can it be faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

I need to generate column `a_b` based on column `a` and column `b` of `df`, if both `a` and `b` are greater than 0, `a_b` is assigned a value of 1, if both `a` and `b` are less than 0, `a_b` is assigned a value of -1, I am using double `np.where` .

My code is as follows, where `generate_data` generates `demo data` and `get_result` is used for `production`, where `get_result` needs to be run `4 million times`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)


def generate_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    _df = pd.DataFrame(rand.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10,7)), columns=['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6'])
    return _df


def get_result(_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    a = _df.a.to_numpy()
    for col in ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']:
        b = _df[col].to_numpy()
        _df[f'a_{col}'] = np.where(
            (a > 0) & (b > 0), 1., np.where(
                (a < 0) & (b < 0), -1., 0.)
        )
    return _df


def main():
    df = generate_data()
    print(df)
    df = get_result(df)
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Data generated by generate_data:

```
          a        b1        b2        b3        b4        b5        b6
0  0.273923 -0.460427 -0.918053 -0.966945  0.626540  0.825511  0.213272
1  0.458993  0.087250  0.870145  0.631707 -0.994523  0.714809 -0.932829
2  0.459311 -0.648689  0.726358  0.082922 -0.400576 -0.154626 -0.943361
3 -0.751433  0.341249  0.294379  0.230770 -0.232645  0.994420  0.961671
4  0.371084  0.300919  0.376893 -0.222157 -0.729807  0.442977  0.050709
5 -0.379516 -0.028329  0.778976  0.868087 -0.284410  0.143060 -0.356261
6  0.188600 -0.324178 -0.216762  0.780549 -0.545685  0.246374 -0.831969
7  0.665288  0.574197 -0.521261  0.752968 -0.882864 -0.327766 -0.699441
8 -0.099321  0.592649 -0.538716 -0.895957 -0.190896 -0.602974 -0.818494
9  0.160665 -0.402608  0.343990 -0.600969  0.884226 -0.269780 -0.789009
```

My desired result:

```
          a        b1        b2        b3        b4        b5        b6  a_b1  \
0  0.273923 -0.460427 -0.918053 -0.966945  0.626540  0.825511  0.213272   0.0   
1  0.458993  0.087250  0.870145  0.631707 -0.994523  0.714809 -0.932829   1.0   
2  0.459311 -0.648689  0.726358  0.082922 -0.400576 -0.154626 -0.943361   0.0   
3 -0.751433  0.341249  0.294379  0.230770 -0.232645  0.994420  0.961671   0.0   
4  0.371084  0.300919  0.376893 -0.222157 -0.729807  0.442977  0.050709   1.0   
5 -0.379516 -0.028329  0.778976  0.868087 -0.284410  0.143060 -0.356261  -1.0   
6  0.188600 -0.324178 -0.216762  0.780549 -0.545685  0.246374 -0.831969   0.0   
7  0.665288  0.574197 -0.521261  0.752968 -0.882864 -0.327766 -0.699441   1.0   
8 -0.099321  0.592649 -0.538716 -0.895957 -0.190896 -0.602974 -0.818494   0.0   
9  0.160665 -0.402608  0.343990 -0.600969  0.884226 -0.269780 -0.789009   0.0   

   a_b2  a_b3  a_b4  a_b5  a_b6  
0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0  
1   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  
2   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
3   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0   0.0  
4   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0  
5   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0  -1.0  
6   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  
7   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
8  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  
9   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
```

Performance evaluation:

```
%timeit get_result(df)
1.56 ms ± 54.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

How can it be faster?

Comment: What will be the shape of real data? Benchmarking on a small subset could be misleading, so would be great to know the data size during final use case.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev The shape of real data is also (10,7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you tag [performance](/questions/tagged/performance), I recommend you, that use `numba` and parallel computing like below: *(If we input values directly to parallel function, we can achive `3.35 µs`)*

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import pandas as pd


@nb.njit( parallel=True )
def parallel_fun(vals):
    a = vals[:,0]
    new_vals = np.empty((10,6))
    for i in nb.prange(6):
        b = vals[:,i+1]
        for j in nb.prange(10):
            val = 0
            if (a[j] >0) and (b[j]>0): val =1
            elif (a[j] <0) and (b[j]<0) : val= -1
            new_vals[j,i] = val
    return new_vals

def get_result_3(_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    vals = _df[['a','b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']].to_numpy()
    new_vals = parallel_fun(vals)
    return pd.DataFrame(new_vals, columns=[f'a_{b}' for b in ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']])


_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10,7)), columns=['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6'])
vals = _df[['a','b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']].to_numpy()
```

Benchmark on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/):

```
%timeit get_result_3(_df)
# 658 µs per loop
%timeit parallel_fun(vals)
# 3.35 µs per loop
```

Comment: 1.11 ms ± 42.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: @jaried, where did you run or check?

Comment: Reviewed on my own computer.

Comment: @jaried, I check this, on colab google and get those benchmarks.

Comment: I understand that the performance in my question was also measured on my computer.

Comment: @jaried, OK, have good time ;)

Comment: Note that `nb.prange` is not really a good idea and at best not useful. It is use to parallelize the operation but it is quite useless without `parallel=True`. The compiler will unroll the loops anyways. Btw, most of the overhead should come from Pandas which is insanely slow to create small dataframe (the Numba code alone should take no more than few us). Also note the compilation time will slow down the first execution of the function.

Answer (score 2):

With a small dataframe (10,7), there are few gains from vectorization, so I am not sure much can be gained there. However, you can rewrite the code to be a bit more readable (though this might be subjective):

```py
def get_result2(_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    
    bcols = [c for c in _df.columns if c.startswith('b')]
    bcols_names = [f'a_{c}' for c in bcols]

    a_sign = np.sign(df['a']).values.reshape(-1,1)
    b_signs = np.sign(df[bcols])

    _df[bcols_names] = ( b_signs == a_sign ) * a_sign

    return _df
```

You can check that this gives the same result using:

```py
x = get_result(df)
y = get_result2(df)

print(x.equals(y))
# True
```

However, in my tests, this function doesn't yield a consistent improvement in runtime. I would guess that it might be better for larger datasets.

Comment: 3.29 ms ± 205 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: This method is faster with pure numpy, see my answer for the code.

Comment: Sure, the question did not make it clear that a pure numpy solution would work.

Comment: Since I need to use df, I accept another answer. I also voted up this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered me with pure numpy:

```
import numpy as np

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
a = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10, 1))
b = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10, 6))


def signs():
    sa = np.sign(a)
    return sa * (sa == np.sign(b))


def main():
    signs()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
%timeit signs()
10.2 µs ± 678 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```